# Find any character occur more than 4 times

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to find any character occurs between  4 and 10 times, I used `REGEXP_LIKE` but it's valid just for one character 'a' , I want to find for all alphabet:

```
SELECT regex_test_name
FROM regex_test
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(regex_test_name, 'a{4,10}')
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{4,10}`. Does it work?

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample input data, and the expected outcome.

Comment: try `REGEXP_LIKE(regex_test_name, '\a{4}')` or `[:a:]{4}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT regex_test_name
FROM regex_test
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(regex_test_name, '([[:alpha:]])\1{3,9}')
```

Inspired by [dnoeth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845819/4607488), but since it catches the first character, specifying 3-9 subsequent repeats means 4-10 successive occurences in total.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[:alpha:]]`

```
REGEXP_LIKE(regex_test_name, '[[:alpha:]]{4,10}');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same character repeated four to 10 times you have to capture the character and then check if it's repeated, this is a matching regex:

```
'([a-zA-z])\1{4,10}'
```

So following will return 'aaaa'

```
regexp_substr('hfhweffkjnaaaaagpeg','([a-zA-z])\1{4,10}')
```